# C exiting with perror

Tags: c

Which of the following is more 'correct' when handling an error in C:

```
} else {
    perror("Error. Example usage: $ ./main file.py\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE); <-- this
};
```

Or just:

```
} else {
    perror("Error. Example usage: $ ./main file.py\n");
};
```

It seems both return the error code `1` so why would `exit()` be necessary?

Comment: `perror` doesn't exit, it simply outputs a diagnostic based on the value of `errno`. `exit (EXIT_FAILURE);` is the correct way of setting the exit code to `1` and causing the program to terminate (while still running any `atexit()` or destructors functions set).

Comment: Also, `perror` should only be used when `errno` contains a code which describes the error. That's not the case for errors signalled with `getopt`, for example.

Comment: could you please show more/all of your code?